# I have found two non-printing characters in a database, what do they mean?

Tags: unicode, formatting, string-formatting, unicode-escapes

Seems a database I am working on, had two non printing characters that was messing something up down the line. After doing some digging, the computer shows them as â, then U+0080 then U+0093.

Any idea what these characters could mean? I suspect its something from Unicode that wasn't converted correctly. But I don't know how to translate it.

Comment: The U notation indicates a Unicode code point (independent of encoding), not bytes (which depend on encoding). You should try not to mix things (the topic is already complex, it makes much less manageable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode codepoint for `â` is U+00E2.  `E2 80 93` is the UTF-8 sequence for a hyphen, specifically `U+2013 EN DASH`.

If UTF-8-encoded data is incorrectly decoded as ISO-8859-1 (also called "latin1") it is displayed as you describe.  Here's an example in Python:

```
>>> print('\u2013')  # Displays U+2013 EN DASH
–
>>> '\u2013'.encode('utf8') # byte sequence of UTF-8-encoded EN DASH
b'\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> '\u2013'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')  # decoded incorrectly
'â\x80\x93'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a website that described it for me.
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2012#UNC_DB

The numbers matched what appeared in the UTF-8 Encoding.